# Google Cloud Storage with Storage.Builder generates exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine with Google Cloud Storage on a webserver using java. I just wanted to expose RESt web service which lists google cloud storage bucket data. I had created "Client Id" with "Service Account" Account type and using OAuth for this purpose.

I had activated Google Cloud Storage JSON api service to access cloud data via json api.

Here is the code snippet while I had used to create GoogleCredentials object.

```
//I had already used .storage_sample.properties file for user information.
//getProperties() is local method which read the user information stored in storage_sample.properties
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(
                            getProperties().getProperty(ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY))
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                            new File(getProperties().getProperty(
                                    PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_PROPERTY)))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();
```

Credentials object got initialzed properly.

Here is the code while init Storage object with the help of Storage.Builder.

```
Storage.Builder builder = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                    credential).setApplicationName(
                    getProperties().getProperty(APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY));

//This line generate exception which says that "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"  
//Stack traces says that "CollectionUnmodifiableRandomAccessList.
storage = builder.build();
```

Is there any problem with this code or do we have any other approach which make connection with google cloud storage using OAuth service account.

Comment: Please show the *full* stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response actually I was using two different libraries,for google.api.service.storage it was 1.14.0 and for google.api.client it was 1.18 which was internally creating conflict.

Comment: @Vicky since you solved it, you can write down your answer below (not in a comment) and accept it. This way the question shows as answered in the list and people looking for answers are more likely to find it.